# About CUDA's architecture (SM, SP)

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, cuda, gpgpu

I am a person just starting the CUDA programming.
There seems to be a concept of SP SM and the CUDA architecture.
I'd tried to run the deviceQuery.cpp of sample source I think what works and SP SM development of their environment,
It has become not know which items whether the SP is any item in the SM.

I think item "(14) Multiprocessors, (8) CUDA Cores / MP" and that are true to the SP and SM, but I will correct understanding of the following?

> SM = Multiprocessors = 14
> SP = CUDA Cores/MP = 8 
> CUDA Cores = 14 * 8 = 112

By the way, the result of deviceQuery.cpp was following.

> CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)
>
> Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)
>
> Device 0: "GeForce GTS 240
> CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          5.5 / 5.5
> CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    1.1
> Total amount of global memory:                 1024 MBytes (1073741824 bytes)
> (14) Multiprocessors, (  8) CUDA Cores/MP:     112 CUDA Cores
> GPU Clock rate:                                1620 MHz (1.62 GHz)
> Memory Clock rate:                             1100 Mhz
> Memory Bus Width:                              256-bit
> Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(8192), 2D=(65536, 32768), 3
> D=(2048, 2048, 2048)
> Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(8192), 512 layers
> Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(8192, 8192), 512 layers
> Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
> Total amount of shared memory per block:       16384 bytes
> Total number of registers available per block: 8192
> Warp size:                                     32
> Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  768
> Maximum number of threads per block:           512
> Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (512, 512, 64)
> Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (65535, 65535, 1)
> Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
> Texture alignment:                             256 bytes
> Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
> Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
> Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
> Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
> Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
> Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
> Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      No
> Device PCI Bus ID / PCI location ID:           9 / 0
> Compute Mode:
> < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simu
> *ltaneously*) >

Answer (score 11):

According to [this](http://www.math.umass.edu/~johnston/M697S12/CUDA_threads_and_block_scheduling.pdf) you are correct:

SM = Streaming Multiprocessor

SP = Streaming Processor = CUDA Core

Total SP/CUDA Cores = number of SM * number of SP/CUDA Cores per SM